# AS3 How to split Strings in an Array and put them in an new Array?

Tags: arrays, string, actionscript-3, split

You got this list and you want to trace it like this:

"Bim","Bum","Bom","Bam","Bem","Beem","Beeem"

`var list: Array = new Array ( "Bim and Bum","Bom, Bam","Bem,Beem and Beeem");
    var ordnenList:Array = list.map(

    function (item:*,index:int, array:Array):Array{
    return (item as String).replace(" und " , ", ").split(", ");
    }
    );`

 I began like this, but it doesn't work.
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is generally easiest to use a `for in` loop for these purposes. We can implement the `string.replace` function, as you have been, and then split the string afterwards.

I'm parking all of this in a function to make it easier.

```
function breakDownArray(list:Array):Array
{
    var newList:Array = [];             //Use this array for storing changes, so we don't mess up the for in loop.
    for each(var s:String in list)          //For each item in array...
    {
        //We're going to use , as the character to split by in a moment...
        s = s.replace(" and ", ",");    //Replace the " and " separator with a comma.
        //You can keep putting additional search terms in here.

        var splitString:Array = s.split(",");   //Split string using ",".
        newList = newList.concat(splitString); //We combine our newList array with the splitString array.
    }

    return newList;         //Return newList.
}
```

Barring bugs, here (code untested), output should look like this...

```
breakDownArray["Bim and Bum","Bom, Bam","Bem,Beem and Beeem"];
//"Bim", "Bum", "Bom", "Bam", "Bem", "Beem", Beeem"
```

It can be tempting to combine commands into single lines of code, like you originally did, but be aware that you are making bug tracking much harder. There are exceptions, but as a general rule of thumb, one line of code should accomplish one task, two at the most.

Comment: It might be better to use first replace " and " with comma, then split, then trim components, otherwise a string like `Bam Bam and Boom` will be damaged.

Comment: First, Thank you so much! but this don't work, he says: newList is undefined, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was missing an opening brace. Sorry about that. It runs perfectly now on mine. Also, per Vesper's suggestion, I removed the line that strips out spaces. You'll want to revise your own code to account for that in each result in newList.